# adding custom authentication in vscode extension

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions

I am building an vscode extension in which i want user to authenticate to my web server. I already have a public facing website where user enters username and password and we generate a token. Can I open my website and ask the vs code user to enter their credentials and then authenticate based on that? I cant seem to find an example where I can redirect from webpage back to extension based on button click. Is there any examples that does that?

Thanks

Comment: were you able to dig up information regarding this?